# Can I give lambda a name?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have nice functional code roughly of next shape (`ComponentRegistry.java`):

```
public void doExport() {
    config.exports().forEach((key, type) -> {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem with it that when it comes to log4j statements it produces next output:

```
ComponentRegistry lambda$doExport$1
```

Where actual method name comes after "lambda" keyword and then there are two hints about anonymous classes (`$`). It simply not as good as direct method call logging.

I was wondering whether anyone came with way to properly label lambdas in log4j output or stacktraces because it would be awesome.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a Method which takes `key` and `type` as parameters and call it inside your forEach?

Comment: Lambdas cannot have a name as of Java 8. What you see in traces is actually a name of the method that java compiler created for that lambda under the hood, and it is subject to change. Naming implementations of functional interfaces can be done using method references, just as @Fabian suggested.

Comment: Do you have to use class name in log4j? How about using file name instead?

Comment: @Fabian that adds 3 more lines. One line break for method padding, one for method definition and another one for closing break (`}`). It also adds one more click-through action (and backward navigation as well) for relatively simpler code chunk. After all lambdas were created so we don't have tons of micro methods doing micro things. However from all other responses seems like wrapping in named methods is the way.

Comment: How does it add lines? What about the lines you save when you get to write it as `config.exports().forEach(Foo::bar)`?

Comment: @Kayaman ok, I missed fact that I could use method reference (still was on `->` thing). Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to give it a name, don't use a lambda (which is explicitly an *anonymous* function). Instead break it out into its own class.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers about a lambda not necessarily being the correct approach if a name is required.

One exception I have come across is using a `Supplier` when testing. This can sometimes be necessary in order to defer code from running from a `MethodSource`/`ArgumentSource`/etc. in JUnit parameterized tests. JUnit 5 has a `Named` interface you can use. I created something like the below example to allow my cases to have meaningful names:

```java
public class NamedSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T>, Named<NamedSupplier<T>> {

  private final String name;
  private final Supplier<T> supplier;

  private NamedSupplier(String name, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    this.name = name;
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  public static <T> NamedSupplier<T> from(String name, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return new NamedSupplier<T>(name, supplier);
  }

  @Override
  public T get() {
    return supplier.get();
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public NamedSupplier<T> getPayload() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```java
public static Stream<NamedSupplier<SomeModel>> someMethodSource() {
  return Stream.of(
    NamedSupplier.from("Name A", () -> fetchData(...)),
    NamedSupplier.from("Name B", () -> fetchData(...))
  );
}
```